# How to exclude AWS (ALB) Application Load Balancer health checks to be excluded from nginx stub_status metrics?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx

How do I exclude the ALB health checks from the nginx status metrics?

I have AWS ALB [1] as the load balancer and nginx servers behind it.

The nginx servers have stub_status [2] enabled. I'm using collectd's nginx plugin [3] to collect the metrics.

The problem is that every time ALB makes health checks, the metrics goes up. I want the health checks to be excluded from the nginx status metrics.

[1] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html

[2] https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_stub_status_module.html

[3] https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:nginx

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41603096/56693.  In short, you can't.

Comment: Too bad. And the section about the "proper way" has a link to something that's not considered production ready. I'd like to find something that's been battle tested than writing my own module. Thank you for the links @eduncan911